# awk single or double quote usage

Tags: php, awk

Why does the awk command not produce the same results with simple-quotes and double-quotes?

```
root@vm90:/root# who | awk "{ print $2 }"
...
root@vm90:/root# who | awk '{ print $2 }'
...
```

I'd like to use awk in a PHP shell_exec() function, which uses simple-quotes in the entire code.

This ...

```
$output = shell_exec("who | awk '{ print $2 }'");
```

... works, but I prefer ...

```
$output = shell_exec('who | awk "{ print $2 }"');
```

... this, which doesn't work.

Comment: `$2` within double quotes gets expanded by bash. So in fact, to use awk's `$2` you need to escape it: `who | awk "{ print \$2 }"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) (emphasis added):

> Because **certain characters within double-quoted text are processed by the *shell***, they must be *escaped* within the text. Of note are the characters `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and `"`, all of which must be preceded by a backslash within double-quoted text if they are to be passed on literally to the program. (The leading backslash is stripped first.)

Comment: That is why I always use singe quote on `awk` code: `awk 'code'`